# Help to find a proof in natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have a question about the methodology of natural deduction, more specifically finding a proof in natural deduction.
The assignment says:

> Find a proof for the formula $(P \rightarrow \neg P) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$.

If I'm not entirely mistaken, this works as a bottom-rule (not sure of the correct translation), meaning that if you imply that something false is true, you can conclude anything on that premise. 
Obviously, this being because $P$ can't imply the negation of $P$, but I suppose you can show how you could theoretically prove it in natural deduction.
(Correct me if I'm wrong, I am not particularly good with natural deduction!)

So let's imply that I'm right, how do I go on and make the proof for the deduction? 
Do I simply just close the assumption of $P$, conclude $\neg P$ from that and then conclude $(P \rightarrow Q)$ from that again, before ending on the conclusion of $Q$?

Comment: Your intuition is right. The way you can formalize this intuition in natural deduction depends on the actual inference rules that you are allowed to use. Unfortunately, natural deduction can have many different but equivalent presentations, and concrete derivations are affected by this presentation choice. Can you give (a link to) the list of your inference rules?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Are you able to see this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ks0g74uSC8o&feature=emb_title

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco the inference rules themselves (that I believe you meant) I have in my book here. I'm not sure of the best way to present this to you. The above link shows the presentation I believe.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco (apologize for repeating comments) We have one introductory rule (-> I) and two elimination rules (-> E) for "and"-formulas. One -> I rule and one -> E rule for implication formulas, and lastly a rule for the "bottom" and RAA (reductio ad absurdum). I hope this clarified somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is absolutely correct. Below I formalized it in a derivation in natural deduction.

I assume that $\lnot P $ is a shorthand for $P \to \bot$, thus inference rules $\lnot_\text{intro}$ and $\lnot_\text{elim}$ are just special cases of $\to_\text{intro}$ and $\to_\text{elim}$.

The following is a derivation (without assumptions) of the formula $(P \to \lnot P) \to (P \to Q)$ in natural deduction. Symbols $*$ and $\circ$ mark which assumptions are discharged by the corresponding instance of the rule $\to_\text{intro}$. The rule $\text{efq}$ (*ex falso quodlibet* or [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)) is the special case of the rule $\text{raa}$ that does not discharge any assumption.

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\dfrac{[P \to \lnot P]^\circ \qquad[P]^*}{\lnot P}\to_\text{elim} \qquad [P]^*}{\dfrac{\dfrac{\bot}{Q}\scriptsize{\ \text{efq}}}{\dfrac{P \to Q}{(P \to \lnot P) \to (P \to Q)}\to_\text{intro}^\circ}\to_\text{intro}^*}\lnot_\text{elim}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

> So let's imply that I'm right, how do I go on and make the proof for the deduction? Do I simply just close the assumption of $P$, conclude $\neg P$ from that and then conclude $(P→Q)$ from that again, before ending on the conclusion of $Q$?

Yes, as Taroccoesbrocco has shown.  In Fitch style this is $$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{}{\fitch{P\to\neg P}{\fitch{P}{\neg P\qquad{\to}\textsf{Elim}\\\bot\qquad{\neg}\textsf{Elim}\\Q\qquad\quad\textsf{EFQ}}\\P\to Q\qquad{\to}\mathsf{Intro}}\\(P\to\neg P)\to (P\to Q)\qquad{\to}\mathsf{Intro}}$$